# Laravel: it is security issue to show expiration in signed url?

Tags: php, laravel, url, signed

How laravel works with expiration in signed URLs? Is the expiration protected in any way against manual overwriting?

I generate confirmation emails in my laravel application that have a limited usage time.
Is it possible, when rewriting the expiration parameter in url, to convince laravel that the url has not yet expired?
My generated url is here:

```
http://localhost/register/confirm/19?expires=1654334707&signature=2e44bb1c17bab475bbffb442316ad932723ba50376db6d75cb0c2fe2675d5535
```

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here. Your URL seems to imply there's a model you're accessing (id = 19?) so in that case you just need to verify that the expiry and signature matches what you'd expect for that model (i.e. generate them based on that model). Since the model is in your database you can use it to determine whether the URL was tampered. However, it's not clear if this is the case from your question.

Comment: _"Is the expiration protected in any way against manual overwriting?"_ - I would hope so, or it would be a pretty poor (or even useless) implementation. Either way, this should be pretty easy to test. Just create a URL, set it to expire in one minute, wait, change the expiration and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you : No, you can't rewrite a signature since everything is in the Hash.

You can find the answer  in the documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#signed-urls

Just don't forget to use the middleware "signed" on your route  or add a logic check in your controller or service